# nginx with nodejs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server, node.js

I want to install nodejs and nginx on Ubintu Server 12.4 and set they up for robust working on. Can you provide answers for the following questions:

1. Where should I install nodejs?
2. Where should I to locate nodejs project files and what permissions I need to set?
3. How should I setup nginx as proxy for nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodejs is available as a package on Precise:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nodejs

So, it should be sufficient to run `apt-get install nodejs nginx` and let the package maintainers take care of the installation.

There's plenty of documentation on setting up nginx as a proxy; just look around.  For example, here's the [official documentation the proxy module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule).

For the location of project files, that's up to your project.  They will need permissions such that the user running nodejs can access them.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some links about setting up nginx as a proxy please?

Comment: Updated to point at the official docs.  Really, you can google "nginx proxy" and come up with that.